# PhoneGap GeoLocation from Dart

Tags: cordova, gps, dart, phonegap-plugins

I have been trying to use geolocation working from Dart with no success i have the following JS code that works.

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Works');
};

function onError(error) {
    alert('error');
}

function test() {
    alert('js called');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
}
```

Calling `test()` from in javascript works fine and the Works alert comes up. But when I call `test()` from Dart with the following code neither alert comes up except for 'Js Called'.

```
context.callMethod("test",[]);
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong any pointers would be great.

Comment: Did you try the Dart version in a browser without PhoneGap? What browsers did you try?

Comment: Yes tried it and dosent work in the browser except for the 'js called'. I tried using chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)` from Dart but it doesn't work, or do you want to call `test()` from Dart and `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)` doesn't work this way?

Comment: Yes i want to call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)` but this dosen't work so created a `test()` but that dosen't work either

Comment: Can you please also add the actual Dart code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked fine for me in Dartium and Chrome:

```
import 'dart:html' as dom;

...    

dom.window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
.then(onSuccess)
..catchError((dom.PositionError error) {
    dom.window.alert("Error code: ${error.code}, Error message: ${error.message}");
})
..whenComplete(() => dom.window.alert("complete"));
```

or

```
test() async {
  try {
    dom.Geoposition pos = await dom.window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    dom.window.alert(pos.toString());
    dom.window.alert("complete");
  } on dom.PositionError catch(error) {
    dom.window.alert("Error code: ${error.code}, Error message: ${error.message}");
  }
}
```

I didn't test the error handling code in both variants.